# What is the intended meaning behind the ending of Take This Waltz?

Tags: plot-explanation, take-this-waltz

Margot is on the scrambler ride but this time alone, and just before that we are shown pretty much the same 'baking scene' as the start of the film, where a mysterious 'faded' man enters the kitchen and she hugs him.

Is the point that she also got bored with Luke Kirby's character after leaving her husband? Somewhere I even read that Luke Kirby's character was all in her imagination or it was all a dream, but that is hard for me to digest, since Lou (her husband) addressed him a few times in different scenes.

Comment: Even characters in your imagination talks to you. have you seen Fight club?

Comment: I'm new to this but it was made clear to me that we must contribute to an accurate answer. Your comment is neither here nor there - have you seen the film, because it is very clear throughout, that every scene carries a heavy metaphorical purpose. That said it would surprise me if Sarah Polley intended to leave her audience unsatisfied with a hypothetical story (dream) that never occurred or have us simply believing that the heroine was seeing things.

Comment: I'm sorry if I made it somewhat offensive, wasnt my intention. to answer you, No I did not watch take this waltz. Just wanted to say, that often things have deeper meanings that we usually vet much. Fight club was an example. that's all. and yes, your understanding is right, but what I gave was a comment, not an answer. It's not an answer, that's why it's given as comment.